# Looking for best way to add material design to meteor application

Tags: meteor, polymer, material-design

I am currently building a small meteor based quoting tool application. I would like to add Google's material design to it and and having a hard time to decide what is the best way to do that.

I would like to hear from someone who has done this, am I in right track and what are the potential issues with solution options below, or is there better existing solution?

1. Installing polymer to public folder and use bower to build the client packages.
2. Installing materialize CSS using Atmosphere package https://atmospherejs.com/materialize/materialize
3. Using momentum https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/momentum to roll my own components https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/momentum

Elements I want to use are paper-elements + Google drive and sheets, plus might need more in the future.

Comment: Just pointing out another option using React : http://grigio.org/meteor-react-and-material-ui-the-easy-way/

Comment: Adding REACT to meteor would seem like really good idea, but I think I wait for native integration.

Answer (score 1):

If you go the Polymer route, you will be able to use the `paper-styles` component.  It would require manual application, but it'd give you the most authentic Material Design experience.  In addition, you can use the various paper elements directly, swapping out normal `input` elements for `paper-input`, for example.

Comment: I have been testing all 3 with TODO app. I think Polymer is the way to go for me now.